# HTML form input not selectable

Tags: html, forms

I can't figure out why the form input on the top right of [this](http://finite-element.com/virtualnext/) page isn't selectable. I tried adjusting the z-index and it still didn't solve anything.

Sorry if I've missed something simple, it's doing my head in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div class="wrap"></div>` is technically dwarfing it, so what you're actually trying to click i a clear div and not the input element that's under it.

[screenshot http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2059/wrapj.png](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/2059/wrapj.png)

Remove the `position: relative;` from your `.wrap` style and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `wrap` `div` is set to position `relative`. Turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

Add a high enough z-index to the div immediately below the header:

```
<div class="wrap header_height">
```